# MicroStrategy Developer 9.4.1 and local R - Error Searching for 'RScript' resulted in no matches

Tags: r

Recently I came across MicroStrategy R Integration pack (https://rintegrationpack.codeplex.com/). I use MicroStrategy 9.4.1 developer on my windows machine and I have R 3.2.1 installed on the same windows machine. My project IServer is on a Linux host which I connect to and create reports regularly. But I do not have R installed and configured for MicroStrategy on IServer linux host. I was wondering if there is a way to only have the local windows machine's MSTR Developer connect to R on the same windows machine and run local R scripts on reports produced using I-Server. I installed R Integration pack on my windows machine (where only MSTR Developer and R is installed) and configured MicroStrategyR package on the same windows machine. Now if I try to create a derived metric on a report with default kMeansClustering.R script like below and try to validate the expression, it gives the error "Searching for 'RScript' resulted in no matches".

RScript<_RScriptFile= "C:\Program Files (x86)\R Integration Pack\RScripts\kMeansClustering.R", _InputNames= "Vars">([OPS - Our Price])

Is there a way to not have R installed on I-Server or not configure I-Server with any external R server , but only work with local R installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The RScript function must be installed, and your MSTR project metadata must be updated following installation of the R binaries on your I-Server (along with the R Integration Pack). This is why you're getting the unrecognized RScript function reference. So I see no way for you to use a Metric that leverages an R Function without installing on your I-Server.

Comment: I tried following all the process required and I am stuck at RGtk2 installation step. Can you please help here? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056906/rgtk2-gtk-glib-package-install-on-ec2